# inline-block css

Tags: html, css

I want texts with more than one line to wrap around like a single block of text, like for "Source" & "DEC" fields below, without using tables.

[image]
I guess I should be able to use inline-block to get this to work, but am not been successful.

Below is the simple html I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="head">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
       .tt { color: #7777cc; width:85px; }
       .cc { display: inline-block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="g1">
        <div class="expandable">
            <span class="tt">Source </span><span class="cc">Neutron energy was varied by changing the
                emission angle to the deuteron beam. The activities of the "2"3"7U and "2"3"1Th
                residual nuclei were measured by a Ge(Li) and a HP Ge gamma-spectrometer, respectively.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Pekka: I want the text under class "cc" to start in the same line as "Source". And when it wraps, it should wrap under itself and not wrap under the text "Source"

Comment: That really looks like a table to me. What's wrong with a table - or at least a definition list?

Comment: +1 to above commenter - don't try and re-invent the wheel. The table function is there for a reason, and I'll give you a hint, it's not for whole page structure...

Comment: @RoToRa: I wanted to get rid of the <table>, to allow for a jquery plugin which would do the expand/collapse text functionality.

Comment: In what way do you want to expand/collapse? Using a table doesn't necessarily disallow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use floats.

```
.expandable { overflow:hidden; } /* Clears floats */
.tt { float:left; width:85px; }
.cc { float:left; }
```

Comment: Floats constantly are abused and misunderstood, there's no need for it in this case. This is a dubious solution.

Comment: Completely disagree with you. It will take more code to accomplish the same goal. If it works then it works and that should be that. Less code is better code.

Comment: True, this works fine. I guess I just always favor solutions that don't need floats whenever possible - always seems to save headaches later on. However "It will take more code to accomplish the same goal" is not true. Sorry Seth, didn't mean to be snarfy.

Comment: Random floats do get bloated quickly and that's why using a Grid system makes a lot of sense, however, I've found that `overflow:hidden` on any parent element of a floating element will take care of 98% of your floating headaches...even in IE6.

Comment: One good thing about using inline-block over floats is that `text-align:center` on the parent element will work properly to center your child elements.

Comment: @itsbalur: This could actually work better for variable width descriptions with your markup, you would only have to set the width of the label. I would consider it.

Comment: i couldn't get this to work. I replaced the styles with the ones given, but the display still looks the same. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @Wesley, @Seth - thank you both for your contribution. Seth's solution worked out to be better when I tried on the actual web server. I couldn't get Seth's solution to work on my localhost, which seems strange. But it could be something with my local settings.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it, try this:

```
   .tt { color: #7777cc; width:85px; }
   .cc { display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:200px }
```

You will have to pick a width that works for you.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/FPtAS/

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to suggest that you use the semantics of a definition list. So instead of

```
<div class="expandable">
  <span class="tt">Source</span>
  <span class="cc">Neutron energy was varied by...</span>
</div>
```

I would write

```
<dl class="expandable">
  <dt>Source</dt>
  <dd>Neutron energy was varied by...</dd>
</dl>
```

But to answer you question:

1. `float:left` and `clear:both` the "Source"
2. `display:block` and `margin-left:95px` on the "Neutron energy was varied by..."

Another tip: figure out the longest word you might have in the left column and then set the size of these elements in the `em` unit to fit this longest word. In most cases and across browsers you'll get better results than with pixels.